# Searching other fields with Solr hon-lucene-synonyms plugin?

Tags: solr, solr6

I'm trying to figure out how to use this plugin:

https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms

If I run:

> http://solr.example.com/solr/graphics/select/?q=royalty+free&debugQuery=on&defType=synonym_edismax&synonyms=true

It works as I want, and I get the debugging telling me that its doing what I want:

```
<arr name="expandedSynonyms">
<str>art</str>
<str>cartoon</str>
<str>clip</str>
<str>clipart</str>
<str>graphics</str>
<str>image</str>
<str>images</str>
<str>multimedia</str>
<str>picture</str>
<str>pictures</str>
<str>royalty free</str>
</arr>

+(((_text_:royalty) (_text_:free))^1.0 ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:cartoons _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:comic _text_:draw _text_:drawing _text_:drawings _text_:funny _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty _text_:sketch) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0) ((+((Synonym(_text_:art _text_:cartoon _text_:clip _text_:clipart _text_:graphics _text_:image _text_:images _text_:multimedia _text_:picture _text_:pictures _text_:royalty) _text_:free)))^1.0))
```

The problem comes when I also want to narrow the results down more using other filters:

> http://solr.example.com/solr/graphics/select/?q=({!lucene%20sow=false%20df=title}%20royalty+free)%20AND%20(has_fla:1)&&debugQuery=on&defType=synonym_edismax&synonyms=true

I just get this debugging:

```
<lst name="reasonForNotExpandingSynonyms">
<str name="name">HasComplexQueryOperators</str>
<str name="explanation">
synonyms.ignoreQueryOperators is set to false, and this query contains complex query operators (e.g. AND, OR, *, -, etc.). Complex queries aren't supported.
</str>
</lst>
```

Surely there must be a way to keep the synonym stuff working, whilst also searching on other fields as well? I'm using **Solr 6.6.0**

The `QueryParser` is **solrconfig.xml** looks like:

```
 <queryParser name="synonym_edismax" class="com.github.healthonnet.search.SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin">
    <!-- You can define more than one synonym analyzer in the following list.
         For example, you might have one set of synonyms for English, one for French,
         one for Spanish, etc.
      -->
    <lst name="synonymAnalyzers">
      <!-- Name your analyzer something useful, e.g. "analyzer_en", "analyzer_fr", "analyzer_es", etc.
           If you only have one, the name doesn't matter (hence "myCoolAnalyzer").
        -->
      <lst name="myCoolAnalyzer">
        <!-- We recommend a PatternTokenizerFactory that tokenizes based on whitespace and quotes.
             This seems to work best with most people's synonym files.
             For details, read the discussion here: http://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms/issues/26
          -->
        <lst name="tokenizer">
          <str name="class">solr.PatternTokenizerFactory</str>
          <str name="pattern"><![CDATA[(?:\s|\")+]]></str>
        </lst>
        <!-- The ShingleFilterFactory outputs synonyms of multiple token lengths (e.g. unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, etc.).
             The default here is to assume you don't have any synonyms longer than 4 tokens.
             You can tweak this depending on what your synonyms look like. E.g. if you only have unigrams, you can remove
             it entirely, and if your synonyms are up to 7 tokens in length, you should set the maxShingleSize to 7.
          -->
        <lst name="filter">
          <str name="class">solr.ShingleFilterFactory</str>
          <str name="outputUnigramsIfNoShingles">true</str>
          <str name="outputUnigrams">true</str>
          <str name="minShingleSize">2</str>
          <str name="maxShingleSize">4</str>
        </lst>
        <!-- This is where you set your synonym file.  For the unit tests and "Getting Started" examples, we use example_synonym_file.txt.
             This plugin will work best if you keep expand set to true and have all your synonyms comma-separated (rather than =>-separated).
          -->
        <lst name="filter">
          <str name="class">solr.SynonymFilterFactory</str>
          <str name="tokenizerFactory">solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory</str>
          <str name="synonyms">synonyms.txt</str>
          <str name="expand">true</str>
          <str name="ignoreCase">true</str>
        </lst>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  </queryParser>
```

For what it's worth - the reason we are using this plugin, is because we want to use multiple word synonyms - such as:

```
royalty free, cartoon, images, photos
```

With a standard setup "royalty" and "free" and treated as 2 seperate words in the synonyms, which we dont want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some comments:

- filtering out by 'has_fla:1' will work for sure if you just add it as a filter:

  &fq=has_fla:1

  Not only will it work, it is preferred. The filter does not affect scoring and will be cached for later queries.
- that plugin seems to have versions only up to Solr 5.3.1, trying to use it with 6.6 will probably have issues. Are you sure you just cannot multiple word synonyms working with 'sow' and 'SynonymGraphFilter' in plain Solr? check [this](https://lucidworks.com/2017/04/18/multi-word-synonyms-solr-adds-query-time-support/)

Comment: Oh you ledgend! That is exactly what I needed! WRT we did try using the sow=false idea, but couldn't get it to work (it just wanted to treat all the synonym multi-words as separate words, which didn't give the results we expected). Anyway, I think this will do the trick nicely - thanks!

Comment: very glad to help!